# Make a div background be larger than it within all sides

Tags: javascript, html, css, resize, background-image

So I want to achieve a effect like the following lading page:
https://www.goodboydigital.com/
I have my background image and I can achieve a 3d hover just like that one, but the problem is, I can't make my background larger so you can see the edges of the `div` when you rotate.I would appreciate some help on how I can make the background bigger, I've already tried values like `w:150vw, h:150vh` but it gets bigger only on the left and bottom of the image and zoom in, so I can still see the edges

```js
var banana = $(".background-section-1");

  $(document).on("mousemove",function(e) {  
    var ax = -($(window).innerWidth()/2- e.pageX)/20;
    var ay = ($(window).innerHeight()/2- e.pageY)/10;
    banana.attr("style", "transform: rotateY("+ax+"deg) rotateX("+ay+"deg);-webkit-transform: rotateY("+ax+"deg) rotateX("+ay+"deg);-moz-transform: rotateY("+ax+"deg) rotateX("+ay+"deg)");
  });
```

```css
 body{
   overflow:hidden;
 }

 .background-section-1{
  position:absolute;
  height:100vh;
  width:100vw;
  background: url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/401685/pexels-photo-401685.jpeg?w=1260&h=750&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb');
  z-index:7;
  background-size:cover;
  border:1px solid white;
 }
  
  .section-inicio{
  position:absolute;
  left:0%;
  top:0%;
  z-index:10;
 }
```

```html
<div id="section1" class="section section-inicio">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="background-section-1 anm-linear"></div>
   <div class="col-md-12 section-heading-main">
      This is where the content goes
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Here's the code working https://jsfiddle.net/haofrp0a/6/

Comment: Have you got any sample code? try putting a demo on https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: provide your code stuff.

Comment: @JoshuaDuxbury Done, sorry for not uploading it with the original post

Answer (score 0):

I simply added `background-size: cover;`. If you do not do that your image will keep the same dimensions even tough you change the width or height.

Working JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/e7gmwtww/

```js
var banana = $(".background-section-1");

  $(document).on("mousemove",function(e) {  
    var ax = -($(window).innerWidth()/2- e.pageX)/20;
    var ay = ($(window).innerHeight()/2- e.pageY)/10;
    banana.attr("style", "transform: rotateY("+ax+"deg) rotateX("+ay+"deg);-webkit-transform: rotateY("+ax+"deg) rotateX("+ay+"deg);-moz-transform: rotateY("+ax+"deg) rotateX("+ay+"deg)");
  });
```

```css
body{
   overflow:hidden;
 }
 .section-heading-main{
  text-align:center;
  white-space:normal;
  padding-top:15vh;
  margin:auto;
  font-size:10vh;
  font-weight:bold;
  z-index:9;
 }

 .site-logo{
  max-width:30vh;
  max-height:30vh;
  text-align:center;
  margin:auto;
  z-index:9;
 }

 .background-section-1{
  position:absolute;
  height:100vh;
  width:100vw;
  background: url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/401685/pexels-photo-401685.jpeg?w=1260&h=750&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb');
        background-size: cover;
  z-index:7;
  
  border:1px solid white;
 }
```

```html
<div id="section1" class="section section-inicio">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="background-section-1 anm-linear"></div>
   <div class="col-md-12 section-heading-main">
      This is where the content goes
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I could fix the problem by adding negative top and left positioning to the background div, also expanding it's size, the only problem of the solution is that it zooms the image, but because in my original code i'm using a geometric pattern it doesn't affect much of it.

```css
  .background-section-1{
  position:absolute;
 top:-10vh;
 left:-10vw;
 height:120vh;
 width:120vw;
  background: url('svg01.svg');
  z-index:7;
  background-size:cover;
  border:1px solid white;
 }



 .section-inicio{
  position:absolute;
  left:0%;
  top:0%;
  z-index:10;
 }
```

Here´s the working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/haofrp0a/7/